# Which loss function to use when I want to make to vectors far away in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, when I train the model, if I want to make two vectors close, I can use mean_square_error as loss function. But if want to make two vectors far away, which loss function should I use? Does 0-mean_square_error makes sense? I am not sure whether negative value is reasonable for loss.

Comment: There is no upper bound on the distance between elements in Euclidean space. Unless I'm missing what you are aiming for, what you are describing will never converge to anything reasonable.

Comment: I have restricted the vectors in [-1,1] by a sigmoid function. So the upper bound in Euclidean space indeed exits. I just want to know how to make the vectors as far as possible in this space ? Something like in contrast to the mean-square-error.

Comment: Both the negated or the inverse mean squared error should work. If the maximum distance is bounded you can use the negated value, if it is not the inverse would have a low bound of zero anyway.